# Replace " " with "_" Regex pattern ? c#

Tags: c#, replace, space

So i need to replace all spaces with undescores and if there is no space there it should stay as it is. The only problem i have is the pattern thing can someone post the pattern thing for this problem ?

Comment: Why do you need a Regex for this? string.Replace() should be just fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't gave us any information but seems like you just need to use [`String.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method.

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character or String in the current string are replaced with another
>   specified Unicode character or String.

```
yourstring = yourstring.Replace(' ', '_');
```

> Because i use NetMF there is no string.replace

Are you sure about that? I think [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436415.aspx) class is avaiable for [`NetMF`](http://www.netmf.com/)

> Version Information
>
> - Available in the .NET Micro Framework versions 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, and 4.1.

Comment: unnecessary adding complexity. Why need RegEx when string.Replace works like champ. Thanks, I was about to respond the same, but rather voted it.

Comment: @abhishek Absolutly, he doesn't need to use regex such a basic process. `String.Replace` is exist for this.

Comment: Because i use NetMF there is no string.replace

Comment: @user2684089 There is. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: @user2684089 why dont you foreach on the string and replace manually? Does it make sense to unnecessarily adding complexity.

Comment: Thats weird i cant add using System.String

Comment: @user2684089 I never used `NetMF` but did you add `System` namespace or something?

Comment: Yes it is added by default

Answer (score 0):

If you are really eager to do this using Regex try this :

```
mystring = Regex.Replace(mystring, @"\s", "_", RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

Where mystring is the original string.